# XMLHttpRequest Calling Progress Event Listener when Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I have a simple file uploading angularjs service that sends a new XMLHttpRequest to S3. I have an x-button in the controller that calls a service method that aborts this upload if it exists.

I have had this working before, but for some reason, it stopped working to the point where it is calling my progress handler and the abort handler. What could be causing this to happen?

```
public uploadFile(file: File): ng.IPromise<{}> {
    this.deferred = this.$q.defer();
    const formData = new FormData();
    ...
    formData.append("file", file);

    const abortUpload = () => this.deferred.reject('canceled');

    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", this.deferred.notify, false);
    this.xhr.addEventListener("load", this.deferred.resolve, false);
    this.xhr.addEventListener("error", this.deferred.reject, false);
    this.xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortUpload, false);

    this.xhr.open('POST', HOSTS.S3_UPLOAD, true);
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
    this.xhr.send(formData);

    return this.deferred.promise;
}

public cancelUploadFile(): void {
    if (this.xhr) {
        this.xhr.abort();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have this in the controller

```
this.uploadFile(someFile).then(
    () => uploadSuccess(...), 
    (err) => uploadError(...),
    () => uploadProgress(...)
).then(<more chained promise code>);
```

and uploadProgress gets called because `xhr.abort()` triggers `deferred.notify` from the listeners for some reason. What would be causing notify to be called from abort in this code?

Comment: How come you have 3 arguments in your `then()` function call?

Comment: @JoaoPereira first one is like a normal then, second is like catch, and the third is for a notify (from deferred.notify)

Comment: the [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes 2 arguments, not 3.

Comment: @JoaoPereira this is $q from AngularJS, it takes 3.